# Directory search in Windows Command Prompt shows incorrect output

Tags: command-line, windows-vista, dir

I searched for the following and it gave me the exact output (folder names changed)

```
C:\temp>dir *950*.pdf /s
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ABCDE

 Directory of C:\temp\e\h\d\20100809

08/08/2010  10:54 PM         1,632,434 09_08_2010_004.pdf
08/08/2010  10:54 PM         1,368,895 09_08_2010_003.pdf
08/08/2010  10:54 PM         2,111,360 09_08_2010_005.pdf
               3 File(s)      5,112,689 bytes
```

I dont understand why "*950*" is being matched against these 3 files...!

Edit1

I actually moved it into c:\temp\ this time and it matches one of them!

```
 C:\temp\20100809>dir *950*.pdf
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ABCDE

 Directory of C:\temp\20100809

08/08/2010  10:54 PM         2,111,360 09_08_2010_005.pdf
```

Edit2

@gravvity's answer is on the dot!

```
C:\temp\20100809>dir *950*.pdf /x
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ABCDE

 Directory of C:\temp\20100809

08/08/2010  10:54 PM         2,111,360 09507E~1.PDF 09_08_2010_005.pdf
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in another directory structure?

Comment: @Dennis - please see Edit1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
dir /x
```

For compatibility reasons, Windows generates a [8.3 name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) for every long file name created, and wildcard matching code (`FindFirstFile()`) checks *both* the original and shortened names. Use `dir /x` to see what short names are assigned to each file.

Usually the auto-generated short names look like `090820~1.PDF` and `090820~2.PDF` and so on, but there are [exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename):

> [...] if at least 4 files or folders already exist with the same initial 6 characters in their short names, the stripped LFN is instead truncated to the first 2 letters of the basename (or 1 if the basename has only 1 letter), followed by 4 hexadecimal digits derived from an undocumented hash of the filename, followed [...]

*Moving* a file within the same partition does not change either of its names, only relocates them.

---

When using the NTFS filesystem, 8.3 name *creation* can be disabled system-wide using:

```
fsutil behavior set disable8dot3
```

However, this won't affect *existing* names.

Comment: +1 Brilliant answer! (perhaps not so brilliant implementation)

Answer (score 0):

I have that problem, and was tempted to use fsutil to disable short names systemwide, but decided against it.  Instead I found out you can use fsutil.exe to [associate the file with a better short name](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/01/27/362105.aspx), as in:

`fsutil.exe file setshortname 175002886.pdf ~1752886.pdf`

You will need to do this as an administrator.