# WinXP dir command: 3 and 4 char extensions are the same?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, dir

I'm trying to recursively search a directory tree to find all of the `.asp` files using the following command:

```
dir *.asp /s
```

For some reason, this returns not only the asp files, but also the aspx files.

How can I force it to ignore the aspx files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dir /x
```

For compatibility reasons, Windows generates a [8.3 name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) for every long file name created, and wildcard matching code (`FindFirstFile()`) checks *both* the original and shortened names. Use `dir /x` to see what short names are assigned to each file.

The "extension" part of a 8.3 name is *always* created by simply truncating the last extension to at most 3 characters: `.aspx` to `.ASP`

---

When using the NTFS filesystem, 8.3 name *creation* can be disabled system-wide using:

```
fsutil behavior set disable8dot3
```

However, this won't affect *existing* names. You will have to [rename each file](http://pastie.org/1505787) and then rename it back to its original name.

---

See also: [Directory search in Windows Command Prompt shows incorrect output!](https://superuser.com/questions/235504/directory-search-in-windows-command-prompt-shows-incorrect-output/)

Comment: Well, that's a pretty good explanation of why - but it seems like there isn't a way to then force the dir command to ignore the aspx files?

Comment: @chris: No. But you can either _remove_ the 8.3 names from your system (will likely save you a lot of trouble later), or filter the `dir` output with `dir /b/s *.asp | findstr /ile .asp` -- this discards lines that do not end with `.asp`.

Comment: according to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/370306/241386) you can use `fsutil 8dot3name strip directory` to remove the existing names, no need to rename them

Comment: [Why does FindFirstFile find short names?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050720-16/?p=34883)

Comment: The behavior can vary between volumes: https://superuser.com/q/825615/213663#1806041

Answer (score 0):

Interesting - seems to be a bug...

Considering, I would pipe it through find like so:

```
dir /s *.asp | find /i /v ".aspx "
```

Comment: it's not a bug, as per grawity's answer. But why do you leave a space at the end of aspx?

Comment: @phuclv, the trailing _space_ must be removed, because it becaome part of the search string otherwise; anyway, this approach would also exclude files that have `.aspx` somewhere in the middle of their names, like `file.aspx.name.asp`, which should actually be included...

Answer (score 0):

Of course this varies according to what command interpreter's `DIR` command one uses.  The [`DIR` command in Take Command](http://jpsoft.com./help/dir.htm), for example, [only matches long names by default](http://jpsoft.com./help/lfnsearch.htm) and so doesn't exhibit this behaviour. ([Matching of short as well as long names can be turned on](http://jpsoft.com./help/index.htm?wildcards.htm#sfn) for compatibility with CMD's `DIR` command.)  So there are ways to address this that don't require `FSUTIL` and administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [PowerShell](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929), you can use:

```
dir *.asp -r | remove-item
```

If you don't have PowerShell, why not?

Answer (score 0):

As user [grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686) already said in [their answer](https://superuser.com/a/238930), it is because the [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) used by `cmd`'s internal commands and several external ones also match against [8.3 file names](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-filenames.html), which are enabled by default.

To work around that, there are several ways, some of which I want to show you:

---

You can use [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to filter the file names returned by [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html):

```cmd
dir /S /B /A:-D "*.asp" | findstr /IEC:".asp"
```

This does not even match files that have `.asp` somewhere in their names (like `file.asp.aspx`), nor does it exclude files that have `.aspx` in their names (like `file.aspx.asp`).

The switch `/B` lets `dir` return a pure list of file names/paths, which can be filtered properly. The option `/A:-D` excludes any matching directories.

---

Alternatively, the [`where` command](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) could be used, which handles wildcards differently than `dir`:

```cmd
where /R "." "*.asp"
```

The disadvantage is that this command also regards the content of the `PATHEXT` variable, so this would also match a file that ends in `.asp.exe`, given that `.EXE` is contained in `PATHEXT`; to avoid that, you could temporarily clear the `PATHEXT` variable (by `set "PATHEXT_BACKUP=%PATHEXT%" & set "PATHEXT="`) and restore it later (by `set "PATHEXT=%PATHEXT_BACKUP%" & set "PATHEXT_BACKUP="`).

---

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/972754) by user [Konrad](https://superuser.com/users/497128) shows a way to change the default behaviour of creating 8.3 file names of items with an extension with more than 3 characters, which in turn prevents most of such unintended matches. But unfortunately this does not change any current 8.3 file names. And of course there could theoretically be situations where the 8.3 file names are still matching although quite unlikely.

I have to admit that I did not yet test this...