# cmd.exe: "del *.txt" also removes *.txt1 etc

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WinXP dir command: 3 and 4 char extensions are the same?](https://superuser.com/questions/238900/winxp-dir-command-3-and-4-char-extensions-are-the-same)

I have been annoyed by a strange behavior of cmd.exe for a long time (at least WinXP and Windows7). A command like `del *.txt` will also remove `*.txt1` files (any number of characters after '.txt' will do). Is this a well known bug or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an occasionally-encountered somewhat-known?

[An explanation of the behavior is here](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/win32-cli-search-wildcard-matching.html), complete with a possible work-around.

Summary: It comes from the way NTFS handles short (8.3) filenames, for compatibility with older stuff that can't handle "new-fangled" long filenames.  `dir /x` can be used to view the short filename, like so:

```
C:\>dir /x *~*
 ...
02/25/2011  08:18 AM    <DIR>          DOCUME~1     Documents and Settings
05/28/2011  12:02 AM    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
 ...
```

Extensions longer than three characters will simply be truncated for their short filename; so `.txt1`, `.txtxtxtxt`, `.txt_file`, etc, all become `.txt`.

Answer (score 6):

Files with more than 4 letters in the extension (and other rules of course also apply), get a short name, so for example "foo.txt1" has the shortname "foo~1.txt". `DEL` (like `DIR` and possibly most other `cmd.exe` builtin commands) will also operate on shortnames. For a discussion on a related topic see [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050720-16/?p=34883).

Answer (score 2):

Would this be on a FAT/VFAT filesystem?  If so, you're getting bitten by the hackery used to represent names that don't fit into the 8.3 schema; there's a `DIR` option that shows you the mangled short names, which will begin with the actual file name but have a `~` and a number before the extension, then the extension is capped at 3 characters.  (Example:  `C:\Program Files` usually translates to `C:\PROGRA~1`.)  A wildcard may unexpectedly match these names.  <s>This should *not* happen on NTFS or (I think) on network shares.</s> except that DOS still hasn't died, it seems....

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use [`Forfiles`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551%28WS.10%29.aspx) command for a workaround

Eg.

```
Forfiles  -s -m *.txt -c "cmd /C del /q @path"
```

Matches only `txt` endings.