# Deleting *.htm files also deleted *.html files

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

What is going on here??

Bunch of *.html and *.htm files in my directory, I do a `del *.htm` and after that the *.html files are also gone:

[image]

I noticed it happening in Total Commander when I typed the command, then checked that it also happens in a (CMD) command window.

The extension is not essential, the same happens with e.g. fantasy extensions *.bon and *.bonk

Win XP SP3

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinXP dir command: 3 and 4 char extensions are the same?](http://superuser.com/questions/238900/winxp-dir-command-3-and-4-char-extensions-are-the-same), [cmd.exe: “del *.txt” also removes *.txt1 etc](http://superuser.com/questions/306038/cmd-exe-del-txt-also-removes-txt1-etc?rq=1)