# Copy file names with a certain number of characters in command line (CMD)

Tags: windows, command-line, regex, cmd.exe, dir

I need to copy all text files on one folder whose names are five characters long. I know this command is for listing:

```
$ dir folder /B | findstr /R "^.....\.txt"
```

but I want to copy all files whose names are listed by the above command
to a different folder.

Answer (score 5):

I was asking (not only to myself) *"doesn't it work a simple..."*?

```
copy  C:\ORIG_DIR\?????.txt C:\Dest_Dir
```

Thanks to G-Man it is tested that **in *powershell* it works**, meanwhile in *cmd.exe* the above command will copy each match up to five characters and with all the extension that start with `.txt`.

> Question mark (?)
>
> Use the question mark as a substitute for a single character in a name. For example, if you type gloss?.doc, you will locate the file Glossy.doc or Gloss1.doc but not Glossary.doc.

Reference:

- [Wildcards](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/find_c_search_wildcard.mspx?mfr=true) under windows.
- [Powershell, text and regular expressions](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/03/06/chapter-13-text-and-regular-expressions.aspx#putting-characters-first-at-line-beginnings).

Comment: (1) D’Oh!  Brain freeze.  I took one look at the question and the first two answers, and I forgot about `?`.  But: (2) Did you try it?  On my machine, `?????.txt` matches files whose names are ***up to*** five characters long, including `A.txt`, `be.txt`, `sea.txt`, `deep.txt`, and `water.txt`.  (3) Also, Windows wildcards have a bug: `*.txt` matches what `*.txt*` matches — including `cat.txt1` and `dog.txtfoo`.  It’s a problem of matching against both the short and the long name — see [this](http://superuser.com/q/825615).  And so, in fact, `?????.txt` will match `cat.txt1` and `dog.txtfoo`.

Comment: @G-Man (1) Thanks, your way of answer made me smile, really thank you. (2) Of course not, I had no possibility to do it (else I didn't put the `?` in the answer). But: (3) From [table 13.7 of powershell](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/03/06/chapter-13-text-and-regular-expressions.aspx#putting-characters-first-at-line-beginnings) I read "exactly one of any characters", maybe it works so under _powershell_ and/or with something like `[a-Z]????.txt` under a `cmd.exe`. What do you think?

Comment: Good catch!  In PowerShell, `?????.txt` works correctly — it doesn’t match the shorter-than-five names or the `*.txt*` names.

Comment: @G-Man. Thanks for the feedback; answer updated. I liked your approach too.

Comment: [dbenham](http://superuser.com/users/109090/dbenham) wrote a comprehensive (and highly up-voted) answer to [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](http://superuser.com/q/475874/354511) (on Super User); it says, “`?` - Matches any 0 or 1 character except `.`”.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in Batch but is easy in PowerShell.

```
ls | foreach { if (($_.BaseName.Length -eq 5) -and ($_.Extension -eq ".txt")) 
    { $_.CopyTo("\Name\Of\Target\Folder\" + $_.Name) }
```

You could also do it by checking the file names against a regular expression, but this method works fine.

Answer (score 2):

In Batch you could do something like this:

```
@Echo OFF

Set "targetDir=C:\Dir"

For %%# In ("*.txt") DO (

    (Echo "%%~nx#" | findstr /R "^......\.")1>Nul 2>&1 && (

        Echo Copying "%%~nx#" ...
        (Copy /Y "%%~f#" "%targetDir%\%%~nx#")1>NUL

    )
)

Pause&Exit /B 0
```

Answer (score 2):

To test with echo in one-liner (it should work with subfolder if you add `/s` in `dir` command)

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /a-d "?????.txt"^|findstr /R "\\.....\.txt$"') do @echo %~fa
```

one-liner copy command

```
for /f "delims=" %a in (
'dir /b /a-d "?????.txt"^|findstr /R "\\.....\.txt$"'
) do @copy  "%~fa" "destination-dir"
```

Batch file

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
  'dir /b /a-d "?????.txt"^|findstr /R "\\.....\.txt$"'
) do (
  copy  "%%~fa" "destination-dir"
)
```

**Edit**:

`/a-d` scan files
`/ad` scan folders
Without `/a[d|-d]` it will scan both 
see `dir /?` for further reading

If I added `"?????.txt"` in command "`dir`" is to reduce the scope of scan and thereby reduce the time to scan.
You can always expand the scope of the scan in the command "`dir`" but the most important is the pattern in command "`findstr`"

I changed `"^.....\.txt"` to `"\\.....\.txt$"` to be able to scan folder name.

```
.   Wildcard: any character
ˆ   Line position: beginning of line
$    Line position: end of line
\.  Escape: literal use of metacharacter .
```

See `findstr /?` for further reading

Why it doesn't work in some case? Because there is no universal solution, you have to adapt the command on your case. If you use /b without /s the `dir` command will produce an output without trailing slash `\` therefore the `findstr` pattern with `\\` will fail.

This will **fail**: `dir /b "*.txt"|findstr /R "\\........$"`
When this will **success**: `dir /b "*.txt"|findstr /R "^........$"`

Just as with a `dir` command that produces an output when the search pattern word is in the end of the line separated by a trailing slash will also fail.

As this will **fail**: `dir /b /s "*.txt"|findstr /R "^........$"`
but this will **success**: `dir /b /s "*.txt"|findstr /R "\\........$"`

Comment: I’ve been so busy corresponding with Hastur that I ignored your answer.  :-)  (1) Good point; `dir` lists files and directories, but the requirement calls for handling files only.  It would have been better, though, if you had explained why you slipped the `/a-d` into your answer.  (2) The first two versions of your answer worked fine.  (I believe that the `^` in the regular expression is unnecessary, but I’m not sure, so I’m not criticizing you for including it.)  But, when you replaced `^` with ``\\``, you broke your answer, *unless* `/s` is added.

Comment: @G-Man You're right as always, I've updated the answer. :)

Comment: "right as always"!  Wow!  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another batch approach:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
      set foo=%%f
      set foo=!foo:~5,5!
      if !foo!==.txt (
            (This filename (%%f) matches the pattern ?????.txt; do what you want with it.)
      )
)
```

The `!foo:~5,5!` is an instance of the
`!variable:~offset:length!`
substring mechanism;
it extracts the substring of the filename starting at the 6th character
(offset 5) and with a length of 5
(enough to capture `.txt` plus one character more, if there is more). 
So variable `foo` has the value `.txt`
if the 6th, 7th, 8th, and 9th characters of the filename
are `.`, `t`, `x`, and `t`, and there is no 10th character.

Comment: I thought I you compare `!foo:~0,5!.txt` with `!foo!`

Comment: Yes, I guess that would work, too.