# Windows CMD: "dir *.cpp" wildcard matches "main.cpp_" and "main.cpp2"

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, wildcards

Here is the content of the directory:

```
λ dir /b "..\src\"
main.c
main.c_
main.c2
main.cpp
main.cpp_
main.cpp2
```

This works as expected:

```
λ dir /b "..\src\*.c"
main.c
```

This doesn't:

```
λ dir /b "..\src\*.cpp"
main.cpp
main.cpp_
main.cpp2
```

Why does this wildcard match **main.cpp_** and **main.cpp2**?

What is a working solution to list only *.cpp files in a directory?

EDIT: it is not a duplicate of [cmd has wildcard bug?](https://superuser.com/questions/920347/cmd-has-wildcard-bug)

Comment: There are probably other potential duplicate targets as well; I recommend looking through questions [tagged "wildcards"](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wildcards).

Comment: [Long filenames, NTFS and legal filename characters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-filenames.html) - "Enable or Disable 8.3 filenames in NTFS ...`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem] NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation=1` to disable - default is enabled.

Comment: There isn't a bug.  As been explained.  The syntax your are using is behaving as it was designed.  The title of the duplicate is poor, since there isn't a bug, but it is a duplicate.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've found a solution without using powershell:

```
λ dir /b "..\src\" | findstr /r /c:".*\.cpp$"
```

Comment: Strange. I read your original post as a question, not as a problem. That's why I gave an answer instead of a solution to a problem... If this works for you, please accept your own answer, so this question will be closed.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't been clear enough! I've found out that I cannot accept my own answer until 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

Because the extension is more than 3 characters long and you're using a command interpeter which has a lot of backward compatibility code for 16 bit apps. If you were to run the same command in PowerShell it would behave as expected.

**Edit because i can't respond to comments**

Yes, just run powershell.exe and then issue the same command, less the /b flag.

**Edit 2**

As far as i'm aware, no there would not be a solution unless you wanted to write your own `dir` program. And regarding powershell, it would be a good idea to start familiarizing yourself with it, as i'm sure Microsoft is trying to kill off the legacy DOS interpreter.

Comment: Thanks! So is there a solution?

Comment: Is there a solution _without_ using powershell?

Comment: [Long filenames, NTFS and legal filename characters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-filenames.html) - "Enable or Disable 8.3 filenames in NTFS ...`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation=1`"

Answer (score 1):

Although indeed a bit weird, it works [as specified](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121.aspx) (italic marking by me):

> You can use wildcard characters (* or?), to represent one or more
>   characters of a file name and to display a subset of files or
>   subdirectories.
>
> Asterisk (*): Use the asterisk as a substitute for any string of
>   characters, for example:
>
> dir *.txt lists all files in the current directory with extensions
>   that *begin with* .txt, such as .txt, .txt1, .txt_old.
>
> dir read*.txt lists all files in the current directory that begin with
>   "read" and with extensions that begin with .txt, such as .txt, .txt1,
>   or .txt_old.
>
> dir read*.* lists all files in the current directory that begin with
>   "read" with any extension.
>
> *The asterisk wildcard always uses short file name mapping, so you
>   might get unexpected results*.

Comment: It might be worth adding to your answer that `dir /x ...` will show both the short and long filenames.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence, I wonder what happens when one turns off 8.3 short filenames in the file system? (`fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 1`)

Comment: So can you tell me where on [cmd has wildcard bug?](http://superuser.com/questions/920347/cmd-has-wildcard-bug) there's a solution to the problem described here? How can you list *.cpp files in a directory?

Comment: The first answer says: "Use dir /x to show (and work with) short versions of filenames". So `dir /x *.cpp` should work (not tested).

Comment: Except I don't want to show or work with short versions of filenames, I just want to list *.cpp files in a directory...
`λ dir /x "..\src\*.cpp" | find "/"`
`09/09/2015  17:52            51 605              main.cpp`
`09/09/2015  17:52            51 605 MAIN~1.CPP   main.cpp_`
`09/09/2015  17:52            51 605 MAIN~2.CPP   main.cpp2`