# Move only files of a given extension while preserving folder structure

Tags: file-management, robocopy, wildcards

I'm trying to backup all of my programs I've written without any of the other stuff, and their location in the folder structure is important because it helps me know what the program is for. Luckily I found this exact questions here already ([Windows 7 - Move only files of a given extension while preserving folder structure](https://superuser.com/questions/112537/windows-7-move-only-files-of-a-given-extension-while-preserving-folder-structu)), and the answer (Robocopy) works nearly perfectly. But unfortunately when I search for "*.sas" it includes all "*.sasb7dat" files, and while the .sas files are the plain text files I want, the .sasb7dat are data files (that are occasionally massive) that I very much do NOT want. Is there a way to restrict the search to only .sas files?

Comment: Possibly related: [Windows wildcards with files having more than 3 characters extensions](https://superuser.com/q/825615/354511)

Comment: Possibly related: [Exclude directories from Windows Search by wildcard](https://superuser.com/q/235799/354511)

Comment: Possibly related: [“dir *.cpp” wildcard matches “main.cpp_” and “main.cpp2”](https://superuser.com/q/971052/354511)

Comment: Possibly related: [dir command: 3 and 4 char extensions are the same?](https://superuser.com/q/238900/354511)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `/XA:[RASHCNETO]` or `/XF` switches to exclude files with specifics attributes.

- For example:  `/XF *.sasb7dat`

  - Also see `RoboCopy /?`, [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), [TechNet Wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx), or [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx)

One could also use the min/max exclusion switches.

- **For example:**

  - *Size:*

    - `/MAX:n - MAXimum file size - exclude files bigger than n bytes`
    - `/MIN:n - MINimum file size - exclude files smaller than n bytes`
  - *Age:*

    - `/MAXAGE:n - MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date`
    - `/MINAGE:n - MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date`
  - *Access:*

    - `/MAXLAD:n - MAXimum Last Access Date - exclude files unused since n`
    - `/MINLAD:n - MINimum Last Access Date - exclude files used since n`