# excluding certain file extensions in Windows search

Tags: search, query

I'm trying to search for a certain file extension, .pro. I have tried the following searches in the search bars: `type:.pro` and `*.pro`, however, both of these queries yield files with the extension `.properties` and `.project`. I don't want these in my results. how do I exclude these?

Comment: If you use `cmd` and `dir *.pro /s` you will find the results you want, though maybe not in the format you might have wanted them.

Comment: @AFH this search still yields .properties, .providers, and .project files.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, and I've just realised why: Windows still insists on providing 8.3 names for long file names, including those with long extensions. Unfortunately all the name massaging is done in the 8-character part and the 3-character extension is the first 3 characters of the long extension. In its wisdom `dir` matches both long and short file names, hence your result. You can disable 8.3 names or you can use `findstr` to filter the results (as I now see David Postill has suggested in his answer).

Comment: @AFH [dir command matchs both short and long names for a reason](https://superuser.com/q/238900/241386). [Why does FindFirstFile find short names?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050720-16/?p=34883)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - Your links explain the mechanism, but not the reason for it, especially now that Windows 10 appears not to support 16-bit programs. There is another solution: [TCC/LE](https://jpsoft.com/all-downloads/downloads.html) is a replacement for `cmd`, which is extended to give near-Unix scripting power, but more or less maintains `cmd` compatibility for existing scripts; by default its `dir` command does _not_ match 8.3 names, though there is an option to allow this. TCC/LE is free for non-commercial use, and is a slightly stripped-down version of the even more powerful TCC.

Comment: @AFH It's exactly the reason cmd cannot remove those features because 32-bit Windows 7 and 8 can still run 16-bit programs. Old batch scripts also rely on those behavior, like `dir *.txt` being exactly the same as `dir .txt` so MS can't remove them from 64-bit cmd either. Moreover you don't need any replacement, powershell can do all of that and match Unix behavior. Simply abandon cmd altogether

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - Point taken. All I can add is that for a `cmd` user TCC is a lot easier to learn than PowerShell.

Comment: another duplicate: [Windows command line search for exact extension with dir](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2423935/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I'm trying to search for a certain file extension, `.pro`

> I have tried the following searches in the search bars: type:.pro and *.pro, however, both of these queries yield files with the extension .properties and .project.

This is not possible using the Windows Explorer search bar, even when using [Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711).

However, it can be achieved in a `cmd` shell, with the following command:

```
dir /b /s | findstr /e /l /c:".pro"
```

Example:

```
> dir /b /s *.pro
F:\test\.pro
F:\test\test.pro
F:\test\test.profile
F:\test\test.properties
F:\test\test.project

> dir /b /s | findstr /e /l /c:".pro"
F:\test\.pro
F:\test\test.pro
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.