# How to search .htm file within a folder in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I'd like to search for all .htm files under a folder. However using .htm will also includes .HTML files. How can I exclude them?

Comment: See [Directory search in Windows Command Prompt shows incorrect output](http://superuser.com/questions/235657) for explanation on why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching for *.htm  instead of .htm  and you'll find it works and just shows .htm

Comment: most pros would just have done *.xxx anyway. I suppose you stumbled on an oddity with a search of .xxx (your search without the star)!

Answer (score 2):

Open a command prompt window (Start > Run > cmd.exe) and navigate to the folder you want to do the search (e.g. `cd C:\MyFolder`). Then type the following command and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
dir /s /p *.htm
```